# $httpBackend service is not working for me in tests - have I missed something?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have the following test code:

```
describe("EmployeeService", function() {
var appUrl = "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/kursevi-angular/collections";

beforeEach(module("app"));

it("should request all employees endpoint", inject(function(employeeService, $httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.expectGET(appUrl + "/employees?apiKey=myKey");
    radnikService.query();
    $httpBackend.flush();
}));
});
```

I have my employee module defined like so:

```
(function() {
'use strict'

angular
    .module('app',['employee']);
})();


(function() {
'use strict'

angular
    .module('employee',['ngResource']);
})();
```

and my service is just a regular $resource factory:

```
(function() {
'use strict'

angular
    .module('employee')
    .factory('employeeService', employeeService);

employeeService.$inject = ['$resource'];
function employeeService($resource) {
    return $resource("https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/kursevi-angular/collections/employees/:employee", { apiKey: "myKey", employee: "@id"}, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
}
})();
```

I get the following error:

```
minErr/<@http://localhost:9876/base/assets/js/angular.js:68:12
loadModules/<@http://localhost:9876/base/assets/js/angular.js:4408:15
forEach@http://localhost:9876/base/assets/js/angular.js:336:11
loadModules@http://localhost:9876/base/assets/js/angular.js:4369:5
createInjector@http://localhost:9876/base/assets/js/angular.js:4294:11
workFn@http://localhost:9876/base/assets/js/angular-mocks.js:2415:44
attemptSync@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:1510:9
QueueRunner.prototype.run@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:1498:9[...]
```

My karma.config.js contains the following files:

```
files: [
    'assets/js/angular.js',
    'assets/js/angular-resource.js',
    'assets/js/angular-mocks.js',
    'app/app.module.js',
    'app/components/radnik/radnik.module.js',
    'app/**/*.js',
    '**/*.html'
],
```

I'm simply following a tutorial built on angular 1.3.3 (and I'm using 1.4.5) and the code is exactly this. Has something changed since then or am I missing something? My program works normally when I run it, but the tests don't seem to follow suite.

Comment: Use the non-minified version of angular to have more readable error messages.

Comment: When I try your code I got a parse error on your 'return $resource line' line. Please fix that.

Comment: You registered 'employeeService' on the 'employee' module, but you seem to test the 'app' module. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: My 'app' module has a dependency on the 'employee' module. Unless I'm mistaken, when I load the app module all the dependencies should be loaded, right?

Comment: That's right, but I couldn't conclude that from the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you miss depenency on **ngResource** as you are using `$resource` service.

```js
angular
  .module('employee', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('employeeService', function employeeService($resource) {
    return $resource("https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/kursevi-angular/collections/employees/:employee", {
      apiKey: "myKey",
      employee: "@id"
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  });

describe("EmployeeService", function() {
  var appUrl = "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/kursevi-angular/collections";

  beforeEach(module("employee"));

  it("should request all employees endpoint", inject(function(employeeService, $httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.expectGET(appUrl + "/employees?apiKey=myKey").respond(200);
    employeeService.query();
    $httpBackend.flush();
  }));
});
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's not it, I've updated my code with the files array from my karma.config.js.

Comment: @user2352164 update to code that was provided – feel free to run code snippet by pushing „run code snipped”. Show how you define dependency to **ngResource**